# Update Query in codeigniter model is not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In the function update_status the 2nd update query is not working. The values in array are properly getting and correct. Can somebody please help me with that?

Here my code:

```
    function update_status($appno,$value,$user_note,$date)
{
    $status = array(
                'app_status' => $value, );
    $this->db->where('app_no',$appno);
            $this->db->update('tbl_application', $status);          

    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $emp = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_employee');
    $this->db->where('Name', $emp); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {   $emp_code = $row->EmployeeCd;   }           

    $data = array(
                'app_no' => $appno,
                'office_code' => 'KL08',
                'verifi_status' => $value,
                'view_status' => 1,
                'view_by' => $emp_code,
                'first_view' => $date,
                'last_view' => $today,
                'modification' => $user_note,
                'modifi_status' => '1',
                'notes' => 'NA'
                    );
    $this->db->update('tbl_appverification', $data);        
    $this->db->where('app_no',$appno);

}
```

Comment: Can u please write this code after  $this->db->where('app_no',$appno); $this->db->last_query(); and post what is the result is.

Answer (score 3):

Where clause must be written before udpate.

`$this->db->where('app_no',$appno);
$this->db->update('tbl_appverification', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

Please write the Where clause before the Update query, as you have written in your first update.